# show con_name not working in SQLDevelopper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

I typed `show con_name;` in sqlDeveloper but the result is the following error : `SP2-0158: unknown SHOW option "con_name"` ... Other commands like `Show user;`  work perfectly. I tried in sqlplus and no problem there.

Any idea of what's happening here ?

ps : I'm using Oracle 12c on Linux

Comment: What is your SQL Developer version. This works for me with V4.1.3.20

Comment: show is sqlplus's command, not sql developer's, so it is expected.

Comment: @stee1rat you missed the part where I said `show user` WORKS perfectly

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my version is `3.2.20.10` and I don't want to mess up my system as I'm new in the ORACLE-LINUX combination...

Comment: @stee1rat - actually, SQL Developer supports all of the SQL*Plus commands

Comment: @JasonKrs you need to upgrade, sorry. upgrading SQLDev won't mess up your system - it's just a ZIP you extract and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHOW is a SQL*Plus command, but SQL Developer does support all of the SQL*Plus commands

you run them through the 'script engine' which is done using F5 or the 2nd execution button on the toolbar

you will need to be on a newer version of SQL Developer as we've vastly increased the amount of SQL*Plus support we offer

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I don't really know my way around Linux Fedora (I'm coming from windows)so I'm not sure I'm going to try and do that. Even http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-install-linux-1969676.html was not clear as `/usr/java` doesnt exit in my system THOUGH sqldevelopper works perfectly well. Again thanks for the answer I now know the problem is only related to my version of sqldeveloper